# Word for the moment of excitement after creating something

Tags: single-word-requests

My friend and I are very creative. We love to create things like movies.

When we sit down after hours of filming and editing and finally watch the finished product, there is always this one moment where the both of us get very very excited about what we created and we just want to go crazy.

Well I know it can be described as "excitement" but I was wondering if there is maybe a more specific word for it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ELU. Single word requests are very well received here, but usually best with a sample sentence, e.g. "My friend and I felt _____ when we saw our finished movie". You can edit your question to add that if you want.

Comment: You might try "orgasm".

Comment: @David, please note that would better be "climax" (as a noun). The OP's description sounds like more than just a "moment of excitement" as he poses in the question.  I think Tim should rephrase the question if the answers that have been given are not satisfactory.

Comment: @user22542 — I don't answer questions in comments. Believe it or not that was a joke. Frowned upon, I know, but how else can you respond to someone who writes "My friend and I are very creative"?

Comment: I (also as a joke) was providing cover for you.

Answer (score 1):

I recon you could say you're feeling **triumphant**.

Comment: Hi Alicat. This isn't a bad start, but it's too short: the system has flagged it as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. It's best if you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a published definition of *triumphant* (linked to the source) and examples of its use. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. PS that's not how you spell *reckon*. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You experience "**exuberance**" and "**jubilance**"...possibly "**triumph**". Often used as adjectives, there are other celebration nouns to pick from. See synonyms.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/exuberant

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/jubilant

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/triumph

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing a *flush of achievement*. The word *flush* has a variety of meanings, and it can give your expression a slightly self-deprecating tone, i.e. less boastful and more “relatable”.

Try googling “flush of victory”, which is a more common expression. It has quite a few variants and interpretations, among which you may find something that strikes a chord.